# Obtengo el error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 30: invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Buenas noches a todos,

Tengo un problema a la hora de leer un archivo `.csv` como `DataFrame` de Pandas.

El código es el siguiente:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Ejercico_4.csv', index_col=0)
df
```

Obtengo este error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 30: invalid continuation byte

El tema es que he intentado leer otros archivos `.csv` y si puedo. Este en cuestión lo guarde como `.csv`, delimitado por comillas.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias señor desconocido y viejo, me sirvió este ,index_col=0, encoding='latin-1'

Answer (score 8):

Es bastante probable que tengas un carácter en la posición 30 que confunda a pandas. Esto ocurre cuando lees archivos que no están codificados en utf-8 que es lo que espera Python. Prueba a cambiar esto

```
df = pd.read_csv('Ejercico_4.csv', index_col=0, encoding='latin-1')
```

...asumiendo latin-1 como la codificación de tu archivo .csv que suele ser habitual en Windows

Comment: Solo un apunte, la respuesta es correcta y es uno de los encodings válidos para acentos (tengo entendido que ISO-8859-1 también, que alguien me corrija si no), pero las comillas en la respuesta, al menos con mi teclado, se copian como comillas invertidas en vez de comillas simples ' o comillas dobles ", así que al copypastear falla por eso.

Comment: Bien visto, pienso que lo edité manualmente y por error se usaron esas comillas. Ya está corregido

Answer (score 1):

usa

```py
pd.read_excel
```

en vez de

```py
pd.read_csv
```

Comment: ¿Cómo funciona el código? ¿Qué hace exactamente? ¿Cuál es el error del OP? Una respuesta que simplemente dice "cambia esto por esto" puede llegar a funcionar, pero deja al usuario con la duda, lo cual NO es el objetivo de una respuesta, una respuesta debe incluir claridad en cuanto al código, mas no dejar más confusión en cuanto  a este. Usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/452124/edit) para añadir clarificaciones a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Me sirvio el siguiente código para el mismo problema.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Ejercico_4.csv', index_col=0, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un csv que ha sido guardado con otro separador que no son las **comas**. Prueba a usar el parámetro `sep` de `pandas` con el separador usado, por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Ejercico_4.csv', index_col=0, sep=';') #ponemos el punto y coma.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el caracter que confunde a Pandas es una letra o símbolo no estándar como una letra con "tilde" o una letra "ñ" que no se usan en inglés. Buscar y reemplazar este tipo de caracteres solucionan el problema si esa es la causa.

Answer (score 0):

He tenido un problema similar,
el error que me genera es:
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 28: invalid continuation byte**
La linea de codigo:
data = pd.read_csv('consumables.csv',sep='\t',header=None,encoding="utf-8")
La solucion poner:
encoding="latin-1" -> debe haber algun caracter que espera Python y en utf-8 no esta

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo proble y lo resolví con

```
df = pd.read_csv('Ejercico_4.csv', index_col=0, sep=',', encoding='latin-1')
```

Recuerda que en sep=';' debes poner dentro de las comillas el caracter por el cual tus datos están delimitados, puede ser un espacio, una coma o un punto y coma.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).